# Optimize Express + Swig HTML rendering time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, swig-template

I have faced a critical issue.

My application architecture is decribed as following:

nginx -> web app (express/nodejs) -> api (jetty/java) -> mysql

The API application is well optimized so its performance does not need to be mentioned here. (~200ms/req with 100 reqs/s)

My web application:

1. [Express](http://expressjs.com/)
2. [Swig template engine](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/)

When doing profile log, I noticed that HTML rendering time by Swig template engine blocks I/O too long, so it increases waiting time of other pending requests dramatically.

For rendering 1MB text/html response, Swig template takes ~250ms.

---

Here is output of my stress-test:

```
$ node stress.js 20
Receive response [0] - 200 - 431.682654ms
Receive response [1] - 200 - 419.248099ms
Receive response [2] - 200 - 670.558033ms
Receive response [4] - 200 - 920.763105ms
Receive response [3] - 200 - 986.20115ms
Receive response [7] - 200 - 1521.330763ms
Receive response [5] - 200 - 1622.569327ms
Receive response [9] - 200 - 1424.500137ms
Receive response [13] - 200 - 1643.676996ms
Receive response [14] - 200 - 1595.958319ms
Receive response [10] - 200 - 1798.043086ms
Receive response [15] - 200 - 1551.028243ms
Receive response [8] - 200 - 1944.247382ms
Receive response [6] - 200 - 2044.866157ms
Receive response [11] - 200 - 2162.960215ms
Receive response [17] - 200 - 1941.155794ms
Receive response [16] - 200 - 1992.213563ms
Receive response [12] - 200 - 2315.330372ms
Receive response [18] - 200 - 2571.841722ms
Receive response [19] - 200 - 2523.899486ms
AVG: 1604.10ms
```

As you can see, the later request, the longer waiting time.

When I return response code instead of render HTML, by modify some code:

```
function render(req, res, next, model) {
    return res.status(200).end(); // add this line
    res.render('list', model);
}
```

The stress-test output changes to:

```
$ node stress.js 20
Receive response [0] - 200 - 147.738725ms
Receive response [1] - 200 - 204.656645ms
Receive response [2] - 200 - 176.583635ms
Receive response [3] - 200 - 218.785931ms
Receive response [4] - 200 - 194.479036ms
Receive response [6] - 200 - 191.531871ms
Receive response [5] - 200 - 265.371646ms
Receive response [7] - 200 - 294.373466ms
Receive response [8] - 200 - 262.097708ms
Receive response [10] - 200 - 282.183757ms
Receive response [11] - 200 - 249.842496ms
Receive response [9] - 200 - 371.228602ms
Receive response [14] - 200 - 236.945983ms
Receive response [13] - 200 - 304.847457ms
Receive response [12] - 200 - 377.766879ms
Receive response [15] - 200 - 332.011981ms
Receive response [16] - 200 - 306.347012ms
Receive response [17] - 200 - 284.942474ms
Receive response [19] - 200 - 249.047099ms
Receive response [18] - 200 - 315.11977ms
AVG: 263.30ms
```

---

There are some solutions I tried to implement before, but none of them can reduce the response time:

#### Use [node-cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html/) (2 workers in my server)

```
if (conf.cluster) {
    // cluster setup
    var cluster = require('cluster');
    var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

    if (cluster.isMaster) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
            cluster.fork();
        }

        cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
            console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');

            // create new worker
            cluster.fork();
        });
    } else {
        rek('server').listen(conf.port, function() {
            console.log('Application started at port ' + conf.port + ' [PID: ' + process.pid + ']');
        });
    }
} else {
    rek('server').listen(conf.port, function() {
        console.log('Application started at port ' + conf.port + ' [PID: ' + process.pid + ']');
    });
}
```

#### Use [JXCore](http://jxcore.com/tutorials/) with 16 threads (max threads no)

```
jx mt-keep:16 app.js
```

#### Use [NGINX load balancing](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)

Start 4 node processes

```
$ PORT=3000 forever start app.js
$ PORT=3001 forever start app.js
$ PORT=3002 forever start app.js
$ PORT=3003 forever start app.js
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream webapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
    server 127.0.0.1:3002;
    server 127.0.0.1:3003;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webapp;
    }

    [...]
}
```

I thought all above solutions would provide multiple processes/threads that do not block each other when executing heavy-task like HTML rendering, but the results are not the same as my expectation: **the waiting time is not reduced**. Although the logs show requests are actually served by multiple processes/threads.

Do I miss any points here?

Or could you please show me another solution to reduce the waiting time?

Comment: There is no easy answer to just optimize the rendering time. That's too broad of a question. What you really want to do is prevent your script from blocking IO, and you can do that by creating a cluster and using the master to distribute the processing load to the workers. The master's IO is never blocked, and multiple requests can be handled concurrently.

Comment: The issue is that althought I created clusters/threads, the performance was not go better

Answer (score 0):

Creating a cluster isn't going to reduce the response times, but it will allow you to run your responses in parallel without blocking IO. Of course in order to use cluster properly you'll need to set up your own logic for the master to efficiently control the workers. Adding a cluster without proper logic is never going to give you any real benefits. In order to make this work correctly, your master needs to handle all of the incoming requests and distribute them to the workers to process. Then the workers send the results back to the master which handles the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should to check some points below:

->Avoid blocking IO by using template caching

->Split a template to many parts and use load on demand

->Gathering data time has covered once?

Answer (score 0):

The real answer here is caching.

Have pages to be re-rendered everytime when stressed? I don't think that template data changes every minute, if ever.

A solution could be writing 2 middlewares that acts as a "sandwich", rendered routes should have a structure like that:

- request
- get-from-cache middleware
- database ???
- swig-templating
- put-in-cache middleware
- response middleware

`put-in-cache` should write to a very fast cache database (REDIS is perfect for that) the compiled template, putting it to expire in 1 minute, and indexing it with the url or some other (more clever) mechanism (like userid requesting it, or headers)

`get-from-cache` would query REDIS for the "indexed query" on every HTTP request, in case it finds the template already compiled, it should just `res.send` away